# Closest alternative to MAC OSX time machine restore

Tags: backup, data-recovery, dropbox, restore

I wonder if there is a solution (or how to tweak such a thing using for example freebsd or something) to have "screen shot back ups" like in MAC's time machine feature to restore all my ubuntu account settings/avatars/home files etc with as little hassle as possible (and also take a record of the state of my computer frequently without me bothering manually doing so)

I dot mind laboring to set it up so I am open for ideas I just want the end result to work seamlessly and as effortlessly as possible.

If you dont know what mac time machine is then please google or watch a video on youtube to get the idea because thats what I am shooting for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: “screen shot back ups” Do you mean snapshots and incremental backups with 2 clicks restore (as is the default on Ubuntu) or do you mean a graphical exploration like in the file manager?

Comment: both I think I found the software I was looking for its this one:  http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/cronopete.html I just did not set it up yet because I am waiting for the hard drivers I ordered to arrive and then Ill build an NAS with them which I will use for my back up purposes as well.

Comment: Sounds cool! Can you please post a self answer when you have set it up? Thanks.

Comment: Any news on this?